# Creating a new entity which contains another existing entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, datamapper

I have the following two tables and corresponding two entities shown at the bottom of this post.  `time_unit` only consists of several preset records which are `s/second/1`, `m/minute/60`, `h/hour/360`, etc.

I need to create a new Schedule.  While not shown, I have several types of schedules which use the provided data differently and as such wish to place the setters inside the entity (either the constructor or some interface method) instead of in the service.   To create the new schedule, I execute `$scheduleService->create(['name'=>'the schedule name', 'other_data'=>123, 'time_unit'=>'h']);`.

```
<?php
namespace Michael\App\Service;
use Michael\App\Entity;
class ScheduleService
{
    public function create(array $params):int {
        //validation as applicable
        $schedule=new Entity\Schedule($params);
        $this->em->persist($schedule);
        $this->em->flush();
        return $schedule->getId();
    }
}
```

And then add the following constructor in the Schedule entity:

```
public function __construct(array $params) {
    $this->setName($params['name']);
    $this->setOtherData($params['other_data']);
    $timeUnit=new TimeUnit();
    $timeUnit->setUnit($params['time_unit']);
    $this->setTimeUnit($timeUnit);
}
```

But this will not work because I am creating a new instance of TimeUnit and Doctrine will complain.

As an alternative, I can pass Schedule the entity manager, but everything I've read states that doing so is bad practice.

How should one create a new entity which contains another existing entity?

---

Schema and basic entities without additional logic are shown below:

[image]

```
 CREATE TABLE schedule (id INT NOT NULL, time_unit VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, other_data VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, INDEX fk_schedule_time_unit_idx (time_unit), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
 CREATE TABLE time_unit (unit VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, seconds INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(unit)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
 ALTER TABLE schedule ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5A3811FB7106057E FOREIGN KEY (time_unit) REFERENCES time_unit (unit);
```

schedule.php

```
<?php

namespace Michael\App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Schedule
*
* @ORM\Table(name="schedule", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_schedule_time_unit_idx", columns={"time_unit"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Schedule
{
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="other_data", type="string", length=45)
    */
    private $other_data;

    //Not included since docs state one shouldn't map foreign keys to fields in an entity
    //private $time_unit;

    /**
    * @var \TimeUnit
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TimeUnit")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="time_unit", referencedColumnName="unit")
    * })
    */
    private $timeUnit;

    /**
    * Set id.
    *
    * @param int $id
    *
    * @return Schedule
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get id.
    *
    * @return int
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * Set name.
    *
    * @param string $name
    *
    * @return Schedule
    */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get name.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
    * Set otherData.
    *
    * @param string $otherData
    *
    * @return Schedule
    */
    public function setOtherData($otherData)
    {
        $this->other_data = $otherData;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get otherData.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getOtherData()
    {
        return $this->other_data;
    }

    /**
    * Set timeUnit.
    *
    * @param TimeUnit $timeUnit (not a string)
    *
    * @return Schedule
    */
    public function setTimeUnit($timeUnit)
    {
        $this->timeUnit = $timeUnit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get timeUnit.
    *
    * @return TimeUnit (not a string)
    */
    public function getTimeUnit()
    {
        return $this->timeUnit;
    }

}
```

time_unit.php

```
<?php

namespace Michael\App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TimeUnit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="time_unit")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TimeUnit
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="unit", type="string", length=1)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $unit;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="seconds", type="integer")
     */
    private $seconds;


    /**
     * Set unit.
     *
     * @param string $unit
     *
     * @return TimeUnit
     */
    public function setUnit($unit)
    {
        $this->unit = $unit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get unit.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUnit()
    {
        return $this->unit;
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return TimeUnit
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set seconds.
     *
     * @param int $seconds
     *
     * @return TimeUnit
     */
    public function setSeconds($seconds)
    {
        $this->seconds = $seconds;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get seconds.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSeconds()
    {
        return $this->seconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: What stops you from passing instance of `TimeUnit` in entity's constructor?

Comment: @Flying By using something like `$schedule=new Entity\Schedule($params, $this->em->getRepository(TimeUnit)->findOneBy(['unit'=>$params['time_unit']]));` in the service?  I have other types of schedules which use the data differently.  Should I find a way to do so such as making a dedicated service just to create each time of schedule?

Comment: You can create separate service that will be responsible for creating schedules. If you want to allow different types of schedules to be created in abstract way - it is possible to create `ScheduleCreatorInterface` and implement separate classes for each type of schedules + create aggregate creator class that will iterate over concrete creator classes and select which one should be used for instantiation. It is quite simple approach but I can provide simple example in answer if necessary

Comment: @Flying  Thank you.  Using an ORM is very new and foreign to me and a simple example would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is actually not an example of using ORM by itself, but I will provide some code now

Comment: @Flying  Maybe also include something in your answer stating that one shouldn't attempt to do as I was trying to do when using an ORM along with your interface alternative solution.  Would have stopped me from searching for an answer which doesn't exist.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `EntityManager` to entities is a bad practice because entities in Doctrine are used as data objects and hence should contain minimum amount of logic. All application logic related to entities should be moved to either custom repositories or to separate classes that belongs to application's service layer.

In your case you need to either pass instance of `TimeUnit` directly to constructor without attempting to construct it inside entity or expect it to be set through setter method.

Instead you need to modify your `ScheduleService::create()` to allow entity creation logic to be customizable. Since your `ScheduleService` basically implements [Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern you need to make one step further towards implementation of [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

Abstract factory basically relies on list of concrete factories that are responsible for construction of concrete class instances instead of attempting to include all possible logic inside itself. Please find below example of implementation of such pattern in your case. It may look overcomplicated because I've extracted 2 interfaces and abstract class and this scheme can be simplified by use of 2 separate interfaces allows abstract and concrete factories to share common base while retaining necessary differences. Abstract class for concrete factories is used to allow extraction of basic entity configuration logic to avoid code duplication.

```
/**
 * Interface for Schedule entity factories
 */
interface AbstractScheduleFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create schedule entity by given params
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return Schedule
     */
    public function create(array $params = []): Schedule;
}

/**
 * Interface for concrete Schedule entity factories
 */
interface ScheduleFactoryInterface extends AbstractScheduleFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Decide if this factory can create schedule entity with given params
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canCreate(array $params): bool;
}

/**
 * Implementation of "Abstract Factory" pattern that relies on concrete factories for constructing Schedule entities
 */
class ScheduleFactory implements AbstractScheduleFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ScheduleFactoryInterface[]
     */
    private $factories;

    /**
     * @param ScheduleFactoryInterface[] $factories
     */
    public function __construct(array $factories)
    {
        $this->factories = $factories;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function create(array $params = []): Schedule
    {
        // Select factory that is able to create Schedule entity by given params
        /** @var ScheduleFactoryInterface $factory */
        $factory = array_reduce($this->factories, function (?ScheduleFactoryInterface $selected, ScheduleFactoryInterface $current) use ($params) {
            if ($selected) {
                return $selected;
            }
            return $current->canCreate($params) ? $current : null;
        });
        if (!$factory) {
            // We have no factory to construct Schedule entity by given params
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to construct Schedule entity by given params');
        }
        // Construct entity by using selected concrete factory
        return $factory->create($params);
    }
}

/**
 * Base implementation of concrete Schedule entity factory
 * to allow sharing some common code between factories
 */
abstract class AbstractScheduleFactory implements ScheduleFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Basic entity configuration to avoid code duplication in concrete factories
     *
     * @param Schedule $entity
     * @param array $params
     */
    protected function configure(Schedule $entity, array $params = []): void
    {
        // This code is more or less copied from your code snippet
        $entity->setName($params['name'] ?? '');
        $entity->setOtherData($params['other_data'] ?? '');
    }
}

/**
 * Example implementation of Schedule entity factory with Schedules with TimeUnit
 */
class TimeUnitScheduleFactory extends AbstractScheduleFactory
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canCreate(array $params): bool
    {
        return array_key_exists('time_unit', $params);
    }

    /**
     * Create schedule entity by given params
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return Schedule
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function create(array $params = []): Schedule
    {
        $schedule = new Schedule();
        // Perform basic Schedule configuration using shared base code
        $this->configure($schedule, $params);
        try {
            // Attempt to assign time unit
            $timeUnit = $this->em->find(TimeUnit::class, $params['time_unit']);
            if (!$timeUnit instanceof TimeUnit) {
                // No TimeUnit is available in database - create one
                $timeUnit = new TimeUnit();
                $timeUnit->setUnit($params['time_unit']);
                $this->em->persist($timeUnit);
            }
            $schedule->setTimeUnit($timeUnit);
        } catch (ORMException $e) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to get TimeUnit entity', 0, $e);
        }

        return $schedule;
    }
}
```

As you can see - this scheme allows you to have arbitrary amount of concrete factories for `Schedule` entities that needs to be passed to `ScheduleFactory` as constructor argument. After that `ScheduleFactory::create()` can be used to create any kind of `Schedule` entities with different construction logic.

Comment: Aside note: it is better to allow Doctrine to construct database scheme for you from your entity mappings, consider looking at [`schema-tool`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation) commands in Doctrine

Comment: Thank you very much Flying.  Going over your example has been a great education, and your complete working example along with the level of detail you provided allowed me to fully understand the concept.  Your use of exceptions also allowed me to better understand how I should be using them. And yes, I will use Doctrine to generate the schema.  All in all, a great answer.

Comment: I see how the `canCreate()` method is the key to selecting the correct factory to use.  In my real example, `$params` includes a key `type` which might be `time_unit_schedule`, and I can simple modify this method as needed.  Also, currently all my schedules utilize class type inheritance which should still work fine with your solution but maybe allow me to only use one interface as code duplication is eliminated through the inheritance.  Just curious, but is there any reason you didn't locate `TimeUnitScheduleFactory::__construct()` in `AbstractScheduleFactory` and make `$em` protected?

Comment: I'm really glad that this information and example was helpful for you. Of course `$em` can be pulled up to `AbstractScheduleFactory`, but since your question contains just one use case - there was no practical meaning to do it in a scope of my simplified example

Comment: Btw, in a case if you're using PHPStorm - there is dedicated refactoring for such movement: `Refactor -> Pull Members Up` in context menu